# Is it safe to use wxTCPConnection in a public network?

Tags: tcp, connection, client, wxwidgets

I am in the process of developing my first client and corresponding server applications.
So please be easy with me, I am a *noob* on network related matters.

My goal is to create a simple interface between my client and my server.
In other words, I would like to be able to Start/Stop the server, connect/disconnect and send a packet of data either way when connected.

I am developing in c++ and I use the wxWidgets library which provides sockets-based IPC classes (wxTCPServer, wxTCPClient and wxTCPConnection).

**My questions are:**
Since wxSSLServer, wxSSLClient and wxTCPConnection are still in the works and not available, how safe is it to use the above classes (wxTCPServer, wxTCPClient and wxTCPConnection) when the client or the server (in case I am running it on my laptop) is connected to a public network? I assume that such a connection would be safe when both are connected in private networks - please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there an alternative opensource library you would suggest that will allow me to safely accomplish my task?

Thank you in advance,
Nicholas

Comment: security in general is a wide field, since you mentioned SSL I guess you are into confidentiality(encryption) and integrity.  So my question is do you need to allow any public user? or can your clients create a tunnels?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I need to allow any public user to connect, they will provide a user name and a password and the server will terminate the connection if these are invalid. I am developing a multiplayer game, so I suppose only these fields should be encrypted, since all other transactions will involve data visible to any player. But what about packet interception/modification? Thanks!

Comment: Well at minimum you'll need encryption, but is usually not a good idea to mix clear and encrypted.  I mean you'll need to take extra precaution at least with the session if you want to mix clear and encrypted.

Comment: So from what I understand my proposed solution is flawed. Any alternative you would suggest?

Comment: You can transmit the data encrypted, and yes you can not avoid authentication attacks like Man In the Middle but it is OK, even online banking can not prevent them.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use the decorator pattern to wrap the wxTCPConnection class, so that I can encrypt the data before sending, and decrypt on receipt. Any suggestions for an opensource library to do the encryption/decryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this comparison

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_Implementations#Overview